# Plug In Order Execution

Tags: plugin

In my template, my custom plugin is parsed before others plugins, **is there a way to say to EE that I want my plugin to be parsed at the end?**

```
    {exp:gwcode_categories parse="inward"}
{exp:mycustom_plugin:s value="{cat_id}"} //ex: 1, my log file says this is ok! 

{/exp:gwcode_categories} 
{exp:mycustom_plugin:g value"} //should say:1 but in my log file, the constructor of my plugin is called before GWcode Categories
```

My plugin has persistence, and that works fine outside EE 2.5.5

Comment: Is this sample code right? Looks like something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use an embed -- OR -- use Mark Croxton's Stash to store the category id in a stash variable before using it somewhere else in the template.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash